# Cocoa: Making NSTextField editable after a click and short delay (like renaming in Finder)

Tags: macos, cocoa, fieldeditor

I cannot find a simple example of how to use an NSTextField to edit it's contents in place.

Exactly like in the Finder - you're able to click, and with a short delay the text field becomes editable.

It seems like it's some combination of the textField, it's cell, and the fieldEditor? Problem is I can't find the most basic example of how to do it.

I've tried subclassing NSTextField with a couple different tests but it hasn't worked:

```
#import "GWTextField.h"
@implementation GWTextField
- (id) initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    return self;
}
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
    [self.cell editWithFrame:self.frame inView:self.superview editor:[self.cell fieldEditorForView:self] delegate:self event:theEvent];
    //[self setEditable:TRUE];
    //[self setSelectable:TRUE];
    //[self selectText:nil];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.3 target:self selector:@selector(edit:) userInfo:nil repeats:FALSE];
}
- (void) edit:(id) sende {
    NSLog(@"edit");
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication].mainWindow makeFirstResponder:self];
    [self selectText:nil];
}
@end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a better solution to the edit in place problem. I believe this is how to properly do edit in place with NSCell. Please show and tell if this is wrong.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface EditTextField : NSTextField <NSTextDelegate>
@end

---

#import "EditTextField.h"

@implementation EditTextField

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if(theEvent.clickCount == 2) {
        self.editable = TRUE;
        NSText * fieldEditor = [self.window fieldEditor:TRUE forObject:self];
        [self.cell editWithFrame:self.bounds inView:self editor:fieldEditor delegate:self event:theEvent];
    } else {
        [super mouseDown:theEvent];
    }
}

- (void) cancelOperation:(id)sender {
    [self.cell endEditing:nil];
    self.editable = FALSE;
}

- (BOOL) textView:(NSTextView *) textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL) commandSelector {
    NSString * selector = NSStringFromSelector(commandSelector);
    if([selector isEqualToString:@"insertNewline:"]) {
        NSText * fieldEditor = [self.window fieldEditor:TRUE forObject:self];
        [self.cell endEditing:fieldEditor];
        self.editable = FALSE;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

@end
```

Comment: The downside is that cells are deprecated. You should be able to do the same with an NSTextField subclass. I suspect a delegate approach may work as well.

Comment: When were cells deprecated? I don't see them being completely removed anytime soon. But yeah, without the cell you'd just subclass NSTextField, set editable=true, and call [window makeFirstResponder:self];

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution with no NSCell - one user pointed out that NSCell is deprecated and will at some point be gone.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface EditTextField : NSTextField <NSTextDelegate,NSTextViewDelegate,NSTextFieldDelegate>

@property BOOL isEditing;
@property BOOL commitChangesOnEscapeKey;
@property BOOL editAfterDelay;
@property CGFloat delay;

@end

----


#import "EditTextField.h"

@interface EditTextField ()
@property NSObject <NSTextFieldDelegate,NSTextViewDelegate> * userDelegate;
@property NSString * originalStringValue;
@property NSTimer * editTimer;
@property NSTrackingArea * editTrackingArea;
@end

@implementation EditTextField

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    [self defaultInit];
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    [self defaultInit];
    return self;
}

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    [self defaultInit];
    return self;
}

- (void) defaultInit {
    self.delay = .8;
}

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *) theEvent {
    if(theEvent.clickCount == 2) {
        [self startEditing];
    } else {
        [super mouseDown:theEvent];
        if(self.editAfterDelay) {
            [self startTracking];
            self.editTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.8 target:self selector:@selector(startEditing) userInfo:nil repeats:FALSE];
        }
    }
}

- (void) startTracking {
    if(!self.editTrackingArea) {
        self.editTrackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.bounds options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited|NSTrackingMouseMoved|NSTrackingActiveInActiveApp|NSTrackingAssumeInside|NSTrackingInVisibleRect owner:self userInfo:nil];
    }
    [self addTrackingArea:self.editTrackingArea];
}

- (void) mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self.editTimer invalidate];
    self.editTimer = nil;
}

- (void) mouseMoved:(NSEvent *) theEvent {
    [self.editTimer invalidate];
    self.editTimer = nil;
}

- (void) startEditing {
    id firstResponder = self.window.firstResponder;
    if([firstResponder isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]]) {
        NSTextView * tv = (NSTextView *)firstResponder;
        if(tv.delegate && [tv.delegate isKindOfClass:[EditTextField class]]) {
            EditTextField * fr = (EditTextField *)tv.delegate;
            [fr stopEditingCommitChanges:FALSE clearFirstResponder:FALSE];
        }
    }
    if(self.delegate != self) {
        self.userDelegate = (NSObject <NSTextFieldDelegate,NSTextViewDelegate> *)self.delegate;
    }
    self.isEditing = TRUE;
    self.delegate = self;
    self.editable = TRUE;
    self.originalStringValue = self.stringValue;
    [self.window makeFirstResponder:self];
}

- (void) stopEditingCommitChanges:(BOOL) commitChanges clearFirstResponder:(BOOL) clearFirstResponder {
    self.editable = FALSE;
    self.isEditing = FALSE;
    self.delegate = nil;
    [self removeTrackingArea:self.editTrackingArea];
    if(!commitChanges) {
        self.stringValue = self.originalStringValue;
    }
    if(clearFirstResponder) {
        [self.window makeFirstResponder:nil];
    }
}

- (void) cancelOperation:(id) sender {
    if(self.commitChangesOnEscapeKey) {
        [self stopEditingCommitChanges:TRUE clearFirstResponder:TRUE];
    } else {
        [self stopEditingCommitChanges:FALSE clearFirstResponder:TRUE];
    }
}

- (BOOL) textView:(NSTextView *) textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL) commandSelector {
    BOOL handlesCommand = FALSE;
    NSString * selector = NSStringFromSelector(commandSelector);

    if(self.userDelegate) {

        if([self.userDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(control:textView:doCommandBySelector:)]) {
            handlesCommand = [self.userDelegate control:self textView:textView doCommandBySelector:commandSelector];
        } else if([self.userDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textView:doCommandBySelector:)]) {
            handlesCommand = [self.userDelegate textView:textView doCommandBySelector:commandSelector];
        }

        if(!handlesCommand) {

            if([selector isEqualToString:@"insertNewline:"]) {
                [self stopEditingCommitChanges:TRUE clearFirstResponder:TRUE];
                handlesCommand = TRUE;
            }

            if([selector isEqualToString:@"insertTab:"]) {
                [self stopEditingCommitChanges:TRUE clearFirstResponder:FALSE];
                handlesCommand = FALSE;
            }
        }

    } else {

        if([selector isEqualToString:@"insertNewline:"]) {
            [self stopEditingCommitChanges:TRUE clearFirstResponder:TRUE];
            handlesCommand = TRUE;
        }

        if([selector isEqualToString:@"insertTab:"]) {
            [self stopEditingCommitChanges:TRUE clearFirstResponder:FALSE];
            handlesCommand = FALSE;
        }
    }

    return handlesCommand;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my application I have two text fields - one non editable, and second, hidden, editable, and activates title editing by calling:

```
[self addSubview:windowTitle];
[windowTitleLabel removeFromSuperview]; 
[self.window makeFirstResponder:windowTitle];
```

This is called from mouseUp: on view behind the label.

I don't remember why I needed to have two text fields (i didn't know Cocoa good that time), probably it will work even without label swapping.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it's funny, I had thought of doing that but was trying to see if there was a proper way to do it with the TextField and it's cell. It just bothered me that this behavior works in views like tableviews, outlineviews, etc. But when I want a field in a view and want to mimic that behavior of delay click to edit there are no examples using the cell/fieldEditor.

Answer (score 0):

I built a re-usable NSTextField subclass you can use for edit in place functionality. http://pastebin.com/QymunMYB

Comment: Using two textFields is definitely enterprising but it simply cannot be the best way! Have you come up with anything better since this?

Comment: No, I have not come up with anything better. I would think a NSTextField and it's cell, but have not found any examples. The only place I see the type of editing is in table views which has that behavior by default, if you ever come across how to do this with one TextField definitely update this post.